# Does Kudan allow for multiple objects to be places while using markerless tracking?

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, augmented-reality, kudan, slam

I am currently using Kudan AR in the Unity Game Engine. I understand how to place an individual object using the Markerless Tracking mode, but it appears as if the way this works is by using ArbiTrackGetPose, and simply setting the transform of the object to that, is it possible to track and follow more than one point using markerless tracking/Arbitrary tracking, so that I can place objects in different locations in scene, and if so, how can this be done?

Comment: "is it possible to track and follow more than one point using so that" <- using ??? what?

Comment: sorry! fixed, "using Markerless tracking/arbitrary tracking"

Comment: It doesn't exactly apply the transform to the object itself, just the object containing the transform driver script. You can create multiple objects and make them all children of the same markerless transform driver, and they'll all get tracked at the same time.

Comment: @DisturbedNeo I see, thanks for the tip! That makes sense to me, but lets say I want to have different objects on different planes, so for example if im looking at some steps, and I want a different GameObject on each step, is that possible using the Kudan SDK? It seems like it can only be setup to transform one markerless transform driver.